# Does Mathematica support DTED 2?

Tags: geography

I have a DTED digital elevation model with an extension of dt2 and Mathematica is refusing to import it. I tried "dt2", "dted", "DTED" as possible data types and none of those worked. Does Mathematica support DTED 2?

Comment: Have you checked the list of import formats? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html

Comment: `$ImportFormats`